# Internet connection through separate port

Tags: networking, vpn

I live in a country where they have blocked port 22, 44, and possibly all ports imaginable.

I would still assume however that port 80 is unblocked. I have tried using Tunnelblick on Mac and using the OpenVPN port 80 package with no luck.

what can I do?

Comment: What port a website is on is configured by the administrator of the website.  port 80 is simply the accepted standard.  If they have block all imaginable ports then that would indicate they don't allow any ports to be open.

Comment: There are certain networks that use DPI (Deep package inspection) to block openvpn traffic entirely. What you may want to look into is wrapping a connection through SSL on port 80 so that it would appear to be internet traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could [wrap your connection in SSL](https://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2013/11/27/tunnel-ssh-over-ssl/), unfortunately this will require you to have access to another computer on an unblocked network, which it appears that you may have as you are trying to run your own VPN config.

By doing so, your traffic should look just like any type of encrypted traffic for banking, gmail, facebook etc.

Comment: I own a mac, how can I do this?